# Apple Watch AppIcon for Long-Look notification is missing in Assets.xcassets

Tags: ios, assets, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-5

When uploading a new build to Appstore Connect, it gives a warning that "Missing Icon".

[image: Missing Icon]

So I went to Watchkitapp's asset catalogue and I can't find the long look notification icon anywhere to be added? Where as short look notification can be seen. I tried creating a sample new project for watch and found the same.

[image: shortlook]

What am i missing? Where to add the icon for long look notifications?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Having this issue right now.

Comment: Yeas I'll have found the solution. Will post the answer briefly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This was an issue with Xcode 10 and it was perfectly fine with Xcode 9.** The solution to this issue is:

1. Go to your xcassets in your watchapp extension and then to the finder via right clicking it.
2. Close the Xcode project
3. There will be file named as "Contents.json". Open that file in some editor.
4. **Add the PNG's of those resolution that are missing and note down the filename of those.**
5. **Add a dictionary those are missing like longlook and quicklook aka shortlook and type the file name correctly to match the Appicon name of yours which you have added now.**
6. Save the json file and open the Xcode project and go to the xcassets and then you can see like the following image:

[image]

1. It will show as warning which is perfectly fine due to the issue in Xcode 10.
2. Now you can upload the build to Testflight and there will be no warnings for your build.
3. I have attached my contents.json file and image of how the assets folder will look like for your assistance.

```html
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "24x24",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "App-icon-48X48@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "notificationCenter",
      "subtype" : "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "27.5x27.5",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "App-icon-55X55@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "notificationCenter",
      "subtype" : "42mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "App-icon-58X58.png",
      "role" : "companionSettings",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "App-icon-87X87.png",
      "role" : "companionSettings",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "App-icon-80X80@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "44x44",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "AppIcon44x44@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "40mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "AppIcon50x50@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "44mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "44x44",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "AppIcon44x44@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "longLook",
      "subtype" : "42mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "50x50",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "AppIcon50x50@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "longLook",
      "subtype" : "44mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "86x86",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "App-icon-172X172@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "quickLook",
      "subtype" : "38mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "98x98",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "App-icon-196X196@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "quickLook",
      "subtype" : "42mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "108x108",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "AppIcon104x104@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "quickLook",
      "subtype" : "44mm"
    },
    {
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "watch-marketing",
      "filename" : "iTunesArtwork.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "pre-rendered" : true
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  My file was simply missing the "filename" line.  Once I added that I had a  place to add the icons and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my build to pass validation.

All that you actually need to do is add four png icons. Apple watch Home Screen 40mm 2x and 44mm 2x and then also for Apple Watch Short Look 40mm 2x and 44mm 2x.  All four of those are pictured on the middle row above.

A few notes that may be helpful.

1) I'm running Xcode 10.1 but I suspect 10 will work as well.

2) My issue is that I had multiple asset files in a large project and I was adding the icons for the wrong .xcasset file.  When I looked at Warnings under my WatchApp target, I noticed one that mentioned an image had an unowned parent.  Clicking on that brought me to the right asset file for the WatchApp target.  (The "unowned" image can be safely discarded)

3) Make sure there aren't alpha channels in your icon images.  You'll receive another frustrating build error if so.  You can check if they exist by opening your .png in Preview, then export image and see if there's a checkbox filled in for alpha.  If so, uncheck it and save the file, then use these images.